# Model cannot be cast to ModelRealmProxyInterface

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm, build.gradle

I'm trying to use [Realm-java library](https://github.com/realm/realm-java#building-realm) built from source, I have used the below JARs and AARs

- a jar file for the Realm Gradle plugin
- an aar file for the Realm library
- a jar file for the annotations
- a jar file for the annotations
  processor

I have added Realm-annotations-processor as below in dependencies

```
kapt project(':realm-annotations-processor-5.8.0')
```

When we do

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
try {
  realm.executeTransaction { realmInstance ->
    realmInstance.copyToRealm(user)// ClassCastException thrown
  }
} finally {
  realm.refreshAndClose()
}
```

The precise exception we have encountered is:

```
UserModel cannot be cast to io.realm.com_example_mobile_test_auth_model_UserModelRealmProxyInterface
```

Comment: You probably didn't add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Solved this myself , I had missed registering the Realm-Transformer which is responsible for generating the RealmProxy.

We need to add below code to build.gradle of required module/app

```
buildscript {

   repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath "io.realm:realm-transformer:5.8.0"
   }
}
import io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer
android.registerTransform(new RealmTransformer(rootProject))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, I tried many solutions, but only this

```
realm.deleteAll();
```

could help me